# (-3,4) to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I tried to convert $(-3,4)$ to polar coordinates and did the following to calculate it.

\begin{align*}
r^2 & =x^2+y^2\\
r^2 & =9+16\\
r& =5
\end{align*}

I got the value of $r$ correct, but the value of theta was wrong.

\begin{align*}
\tan(\theta) & = \frac{y}{x}\\
\tan(\theta) & = \frac{4}{-3}\\
\theta & = \arctan\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)\\
\theta & = -.927
\end{align*}

So then I said the answer is $(5, -.927)$ or $(-5, -.927+\pi)$.

The answer is $(-5,5.356)$.

I don't understand why they got this $r$ or this theta. How is this calculated?

Comment: In which quadrant, your point is ?

Comment: It is in quadrant 2

Comment: @user112167 Theta is counted from x-axis.

Comment: $(-3, 4)$ is in the $2$nd quadrant. $\tan^{-1}(4/-3)$ is in the $4$th quadrant. $\pi + \tan^{-1}(4/-3)$ is in the $2$nd quadrant.

Comment: How is the quadrant of tan decided?

Comment: @user112167 If you compute $\tan^{-1}(4/-3)$, you get an angle in the $4$th quadrant.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You should find $(5,2.21)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First quadrant

$$\theta=\arctan(\frac yx)$$

second quadrant

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(\frac{-x}{y})$$

third quadrant

$$\theta=\pi+\arctan(\frac yx)$$

fourth quadrant

$$\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan(\frac{x}{-y})$$

Remark

You can use the following identities

$$(\forall X>0)\;\;$$
$$\arctan(X)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\frac 1X)$$
and
$$(\forall X<0)\;\;$$
$$\arctan(X)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\frac 1X)$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $\theta$ is supposed to be in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. The answer $\theta^*$ you got falls out of this interval, so you just need to find its version $\theta^*+2\pi k$ that happens to be in that interval for some integer $k$. In your case quite simply $k=1$ and $2\pi - .927$ gives you the desired answer.